# Call a variable from one file to the other

Tags: objective-c, variables, global-variables, call

Of Objective C, I'm looking to call a variable from one .m to the other .m

This is given myvar declared as an int in Example1.h

Example1.m

```
myvar = myvar+10
```

Example2.m

```
if (myvar == 10){NSLOG("@myvar equals the correct integer: %i",myvar);}
```

However, by default myvar will equal 0 because myvar is called from Example1.h in Example2.m.

Comment: Your usage of terminology is a bit confusing. You cannot call a variable and also the format specifier to print an integer is `%i` and not `i%`. Also `@` symbol should be before quotes. `NSLOG(@"myvar equals the correct integer: %i",myvar);`

Comment: @ Mahesh That's not the point... I want myvar to be loaded into Example2.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For global values, create a class to hold these and define the variables as static.  You can also define class level methods to manipulate the static variable. I call my class appState. You might define myVar as static and then class methods (use the + not -) to get and set this variable.

Here's an example of a BOOL I can access from anywhere in my application.

account.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Account : NSObject 
{
}

+(BOOL)isOffLine;
+(void)setOffLine:(BOOL)newValue;

@end
```

account.m

```
#import "Account.h"

@implementation Account

static BOOL _offline;

+(BOOL)isOffLine;
{
    return _offline;
}

+(void)setOffLine:(BOOL)newValue
{
    _offline = newValue;
}

@end
```

Now from any class in my application, I can `#import account.h` and then use something like:

```
if ([Account isOffLine]) {...}
```

or

```
[Account setOffLine:YES];
```

Note that I didn't create an instance of this class. I'm calling the class level methods. The value will persist between calls from different classes in my application.

Comment: Doesn't work. I followed http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#class which dosn't work

Comment: It works for some of us. Perhaps you have a bug in your code? If you post it I'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you. I've spent at least 4 hours on this. Player.h: http://pastebin.com/zCA1pwDw Player.m: http://pastebin.com/bYm6D7SU EntityZombie.h: http://pastebin.com/D7LPyZaD EntityZombie.m: http://pastebin.com/LAvZLTUn

Comment: I didn't see where you were trying my idea in your code, so perhaps there was a misunderstanding. I've edited my answer to include a code example which I hope will clear things up.

Comment: I tried calling the xcord with [Player plyr_xcord]. Here's the method. + (BOOL)plyr_xcord{return xcord;} But no matter what, xcord is always zero!

Comment: I copied an earlier revision sorry.

Comment: I'm about ready to give up trying to help. This solution will work if you do it right.

Comment: I believe you. I'm just incompetent is all. I'll continue to work on this.

Answer (score 1):

I’d recommend you read up on the basics, perhaps [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html) could be a good place to start. My guess is that what you really should be doing is creating a [property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) in one class and accessing it from another.

Comment: I get the error: property 'xcord' attempting to use ivar 'xcord' declared in super class of 'EntityZombie'